# No Next.js version could be detected in your project, Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies" - it does appear there

Tags: next.js, vercel

I've looked for different solutions but didnt find it helpful.
Going through next.js learning section and try to deploy on vercel and receive this error.

this is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.6",
    "@types/node": "20.5.7",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "next": "^14.0.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.31",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.14",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3"
  }
```

please tell me exactly what steps should I do in order to fix it.
I'm a junior so please try to be more clear and accurate.

thanks a lot :)

Tried some other solutions from the past with no success

Comment: How have you created your project? Using `yarn create next-app`? Please provide more details.